# How to store a multiline string in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to store a multiline string so I can loop over them like the example below:

```
...............#.#.............
##..#....................#...##
......#..#.#.....#..#.#.##.....
.........#...#..............#.#
............#.......##.........
...#.....#.....#...#.....#..#..
..............#..##.#..#......#
.##.....#.....#......##.#......
.#..........###....#...##....#.
.....#....#.#.......#......##..
.#....#......#.......#........#
..#.#.......#..##.....##.......
...#.#....#.......#.......#...#
##.##...##..#......#.#.....#..#
.#.#.......#..#.#......#...#.#.
#.......##.......#...#.........
.....#......#.#.#.....#....##..
.#.#........#....#..#..#.......
...#....#..###.........#.....#.
```

In Python I would do the following :

```
example = """
...............#.#.............
##..#....................#...##
......#..#.#.....#..#.#.##.....
.........#...#..............#.#
............#.......##.........
...#.....#.....#...#.....#..#..
..............#..##.#..#......#
.##.....#.....#......##.#......
.#..........###....#...##....#.
.....#....#.#.......#......##..
.#....#......#.......#........#
..#.#.......#..##.....##.......
...#.#....#.......#.......#...#
##.##...##..#......#.#.....#..#
.#.#.......#..#.#......#...#.#.
#.......##.......#...#.........
.....#......#.#.#.....#....##..
.#.#........#....#..#..#.......
...#....#..###.........#.....#.
"""
```

I tried using `std::string s("")` with the entire string inside of it but I get a lot of errors saying `error: invalid preprocessing directive`.

Comment: By "multiline string" do you mean a string that, as far as code (e.g. library functions) using it is concerned, has multiple lines?   Or do you mean a string that has an initialiser in source code that spans multiple lines?      The options are different in both cases.

Comment: [Raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) might be useful to you as well.

Comment: @Brian yes thank you that worked.